# How to add a picture to a signature?

Tags: email, html, user

As part of our branding we add a picture that links to our website to our signatures sent through Outlook or other channels.

I would like to know how we can add the same picture to our signatures in Salesforce.

I've seen 'official' documentation stating to use `<img src="[picture URL]"/>` but that just shows up the same as it's put in when sent out.

I've also tried a custom Rich Text Field but there's no way to make a picture a link in that field.

Is there any official way, or work around to this issue?

Comment: Have you seen this [Adding Images to Email Templates](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_template_images.htm)? Providing the Document holding the signature image is marked as "Externally Available Image" people receiving the email will be able to see the signature image.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Kieth C](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/887/keith-c) in comment:

- Upload that Signature image in Document Object
- Check the Externally Available Image checkbox = true
- Fill all other required fields
- Save that Document record

It would show preview of image to you. 
Right click on the preview image and copy the URL.
Use that url in your image source. URL look like this:

```
https://cs41.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015D0000000Mjpi&oid=00DD00000003yOH&lastMod=1470296347000
```